# How to programatically install a ipa file in iOS 6

Tags: ios, installation, ipa

we use iOS private framework `MobileInstallationInstall`, it worked fine in iOS 5 like this:

```
typedef int (*MobileInstallationInstall)(NSString *path, NSDictionary *dict, void *na, NSString *path2_equal_path_maybe_no_use);

int result=pMobileInstallationInstall(ipaPath,[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"User" forKey:@"ApplicationType"],nil,ipaPath);
```

But, in iOS 6, this method (`pMobileInstallationInstall`) always return -1.

Can somebody help me ? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

please follow [How do I change my iOS applications' entitlements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871748/how-do-i-change-my-applications-entitlements-to-com-apple-backboard-client) to sign your app and you need to add the following to the xml file.

```
<key>com.apple.private.mobileinstall.allowedSPI</key>
<array>
    <string>Install</string>
    <string>Browse</string>
    <string>Uninstall</string>
    <string>Archive</string>
    <string>RemoveArchive</string>
</array>
```

Comment: @mihirmehta Hello is this solution working, because it is always returning me -1. Any suggestion?