# Install iOS application( ipa file) inside another app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipa

I try to write an app, it can download an application from web server ( ipa file) and install it. Does anyone know how to install this ipa file ? Can i do it using OTA inside app or use command line to install it ?

Comment: You can do that on a jailbroken device. Is such a solution acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it's acceptable, how can i do it ?

Comment: @QuangHuynh Have you tried searching?

Comment: Perhaps you can look for Testflight. They provide a Certificate for their own app which is able to install other IPA files onto the device OTA.

Comment: @trojanfoe i've search a lot but only found OTA, or install ipa file with iFunbox, iTools ...or ipa installer console via terminal in jailbroken device.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? What is the purpose of doing that? Depending on your answer to this question, an enterprise account rather tahn a regular developer account may be the right thing for you.

Comment: @who9vy I am sorry, but this is wrong. That profile has nothing to do with being able to install other IPA files. It allows their website to know the current devices UDID, so they can search in their database which apps it can install by searching that UDID in the provisioning profiles of all the apps they have. The profile does **NOT** allow you to install any IPA file!

Comment: @QuangHuynh I've posted a solution for jailbroken devices that doesn't involve OTA and can be natively integrated to your app.

Answer (score 6):

So here's an instant solution for **jailbroken devices,** which makes it possible to directly install any `.ipa` file from within your application. The steps you have to take is:

I. Gain root access. You can achieve this by calling `setuid(0);` from your `main()` function. You'll need to set the sticky permission bit on your executable and use a startup script too.

II. Unzip the `.ipa` file. Yes, that's right - IPAs are just disguised ZIP files. You can use the opensource [libzip](http://nih.at/libzip/) library for this.

III. There'll be a directory called `Payload` inside. The actual app bundle (let's call it `MyApp.app`) will reside in that folder.

IV. Create a directory in the `/var/mobile/Applications` directory on the filesystem. This will be the container sandbox of the app to be installed. By convention, the name of this directory should be an UUID. For example, you can use the following code snippet for this:

```
CFUUIDRef uuidObj = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef uuid = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuidObj);
CFRelease(uuidObj);

NSString *appPath = [@"/var/mobile/Applications" stringByAppendingPathComponent:(id)uuid];
[fmgr createDirectoryAtPath:appPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];
CFRelease(uuid);
```

V. Find the app bundle by looping through the contents of the `Payload` directory (obtained in step II). Copy it over to the newly created sandbox (of which the name is the UUID string). Also copy the `iTunesMetadata.plist` and `iTunesArtwork` files in order iTunes to display a nice icon for the app and to notify you of updates. Fix the permissions of the executable of the application as well to make it executable:

```
NSString *execName = [appInfoPlist objectForKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
NSString *execPath = [bundle stringByAppendingPathComponent:execName];
chmod(execPath.UTF8String, 0755);
```

VI. You'll need to tell SpringBoard to locate your app and then to reload its installed app cache to make the icon of the freshly installed appear on the home screen. For this, you first update the list of the applications in the MobileInstallation property list file. Here the `bundle` variable refers to the filesystem location of the app bundle, something like `/var/mobile/applications/LONG_UUID_STRING/MyApp.app`.

```
#define kMobileInstallationPlistPath @"/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist"
NSMutableDictionary *appInfoPlist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[bundle stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Info.plist"]];
[appInfoPlist setObject:@"User" forKey:@"ApplicationType"];
[appInfoPlist setObject:bundle forKey:@"Path"];
[appInfoPlist setObject:@{
    @"CFFIXED_USER_HOME" : appPath,
    @"HOME" : appPath,
    @"TMPDIR" : [appPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp"]
} forKey:@"EnvironmentVariables"];
[appInfoPlist setObject:appPath forKey:@"Container"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:kMobileInstallationPlistPath];
NSMutableDictionary *mobileInstallation = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:NULL error:NULL];
NSString *bundleID = [appInfoPlist objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
[[mobileInstallation objectForKey:@"User"] setObject:appInfoPlist forKey:bundleID];
[mobileInstallation writeToFile:kMobileInstallationPlistPath atomically:NO];
```

Then remove the cached app information SpringBoard stores:

```
remove("/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist");
remove("/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.springboard-imagecache-icons");
remove("/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.springboard-imagecache-icons.plist");
remove("/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.springboard-imagecache-smallicons");
remove("/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.springboard-imagecache-smallicons.plist");
remove("/var/mobile/Library/Caches/SpringBoardIconCache");
remove("/var/mobile/Library/Caches/SpringBoardIconCache-small");
remove("/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.IconsCache");
```

Then notify SpringBoard to reload the list of all applications:

```
Class __LSApplicationWorkspace = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
[(LSApplicationWorkspace *)[__LSApplicationWorkspace defaultWorkspace] invalidateIconCache:nil];
[(LSApplicationWorkspace *)[__LSApplicationWorkspace defaultWorkspace] registerApplication:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundle]];
notify_post("com.apple.mobile.application_installed");
```

Comment: i've tried to get root by setuid(0) but i can't create folder inside /var/mobile/applications, could you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: @QuangHuynh So did you set the sticky bit on your executable and used a startup shell script? It doesn't work without those.

Comment: @H2C03 : how can i do this ? i'm new to iOS, thank you so much.

Comment: @QuangHuynh This is not iOS-specific, you just need a normal shell script and `chmod 7755` on your executable.

Comment: @H2C03 could you give me a tutorial about this, im feel ambiguous about this, how can i find the path to my executable file,... ?

Comment: @QuangHuynh `/Applications/<YourAppName>.app/YourAppName`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31269/discussion-between-quang-huynh-and-h2co3)

Comment: @QuangHuynh is there any success, I am also stuck in the same but hard luck. Can you please share some of the experience?

Comment: @DeepikaLalra i havn't finished yet, i've found another way to solved my problem.

Comment: @QuangHuynh thanks for the reply can you please give me some idea how to do that? That will be great.

Comment: @H2CO3 I follow your instructions above and got stuck at step VI where I cannot overwrite the installplist file, is there some more thing else I should perform to complete this? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @QuangHuynh am so glade that you found another way to solve the problem. Am just like Deepika Lara, I wish you can share this with us.Thanks.

Comment: @sovannarith Sure your process has root?

Comment: @sovannarith i've used a private framework MobileInstallation for ipa installation, try https://github.com/kryhear/IPAInstaller , but i still dont know how to make root process, if you know how, could you share with me ?

Comment: @QuangHuynh It give me the error (MobileInstallationInstall) pMobileInstallationInstall = <register sp is not available> any idea?

Comment: @QuangHuynh I've got message asking to check if my device was jailbroken while I installed the app in the jailbroken device already. This is hard.

Comment: @H2CO3 I did put setuid(0) in the main function and set the stick permission you told in step one by this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841344/error-permission-denied-when-accessing-ios-filesystem-jailbreak/8796556#8796556 but still not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @sovannarith Got the startup shell script as well?

Comment: @H2CO3 I did create a copy of app shell script myApp and renamed it to myApp2, replace content of old script with something I mentioned in the link, and change permission and ownership before ssh into device.

Comment: @sovannarith And the shell script calls `exec "/Applications/MyApp.app/RealExecutable;"`, and in the Info.plist, the `CFBundleExecutable` key is pointing to the shell script, right?

Comment: @H2CO3 There's something you need to know. If my process not gaining root privilege I won't be able to create the bundle for the app to install "/var/mobile/Applications/#####", isn't it?

Comment: @sovannarith Well, that folder belongs to user "mobile", so it may not be the case, but how is that related?

Comment: @H2CO3 I thought if It's the case it mean that I already have root access, cos the bundle was created.

Comment: @sovannarith What does `getuid()` return? `0` or `501`?

Comment: @H2CO3 Actually I don't know since it's not attache to Xcode.

Comment: @QuangHuynh Can you please join this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32136/chat, as just want to discuss a few things related to this topic?

Comment: @sovannarith I don't see your problem there. You don't need all of Xcode for this at all. I just asked you for the return value of a function.

Comment: @QuangHuynh I have used the same but its showing error "MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1" so any idea for that?Secondly If the ipa is composed of that provisioning profile that does not contains UDID of the target device so will this code work?

Comment: @DeepikaLalra you should try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817569/how-to-programatically-install-a-ipa-file-in-ios-6 for solution ?

Comment: @QuangHuynh thanks for the response and yes this is the exact error that I was facing. Also this is the case where we created the ipa by our own but what if client has a already existing store of IPA so I can't do modification to existing file now if I just have to download and install them how should I proceed ?

Comment: @DeepikaLalra I don't have time to try it yet, if there's result I'll share.

Comment: @QuangHuynh Regarding to gain root access for your app, please have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841344/error-permission-denied-when-accessing-ios-filesystem-jailbreak/8796556#8796556 I did get root access with this answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 I did get the root privilege, the result of getuid() is 0. But when I continue to step VI, the file "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist" was not found. Any suggestion?

Comment: @sovannarith Well, that's strange, I have it on all of my devices, and I've successfully tested this technique in a real app. Haven't you made a typo? If not: what if you try to create the file if nonexistent?

Comment: @H2CO3 I did found it last time in that path. Isn't it recreated every times after refresh the springboard?

Comment: @sovannarith No, it isn't (AFAIK).

Comment: @H2CO3 Is this line of code, step VI, remove the file? remove("/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist");

Comment: @sovannarith Yes, it does. It's the C standard library function for deleting a file.

Comment: @H2CO3 So the file was deleted at the end of installation, why it exists in your case?

Comment: @sovannarith IDK, presumably SpringBoard recreated it. So have you tried commenting out that line and see if it works?

Comment: @H2CO3 I feel like something wrong in my code that springboard didn't recreate it, and now it was already deleted. What should I do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32310/discussion-between-sovannarith-and-h2co3)

Comment: @H2CO3 Ok I'll do it. But can I ask you some more?

Comment: @H2CO3 When you notify SpringBoard to reload the list of all applications at the last step, what else you did beside writing that bunch of codes?

Comment: @sovannarith I waited until it completed. (Well **what** do you expect? Is there some big secret I would keep for myself and not post it in the answer? Or what?)

Comment: @H2CO3 I didn't mean like that, but fist when I copy your code and past, Xcode not recognize the class "LSApplicationWorkspace", I then check online and import in my project the header of the class. But I have only the header.

Comment: @sovannarith And that's enough. `objc_getClass()` takes care of the rest. If you are messing with undocumented/private stuff, you are expected to 1. run into problems and 2. be able to resolve them on your own.

Comment: @H2CO3 I have tried all the possible ways to perform this task but vain and I have to accomplish this task any how,can you please share you personal email ID, want to discuss the issue in detail.

Comment: @H2CO3 I tried all the ways in the discussion, and at last I can install some apps while some other crash immediately at the launch (ex. Facebook messenger, Facebook, CNN for iPhone). Do you have any idea for this crash???

Comment: @VibolTeav Maybe the applications are codesigned (i. e. encrypted, not cracked properly).

Comment: @H2CO3 But I try installing those apps via iFunBox and they work fine.

Comment: Hiii, i have used your code to install .ipa file in iOS7, it is working fine, but the code for notifying SpringBoard to reload the list of all applications is not working in my case, does you know what may the problem,(if i restart my device, app will show up but i dont want to restart iphone everytime i install ipa file), help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via OTA distribution, see
http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad871e

An example plist can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/hramos/774468

Note that you either need the Enterprise Developer Program or collect the UDIDs of your users and include them in your ad-hoc provisioning profile.

Comment: Could i use OTA technique without using Safari but using objective-C code ?

Comment: Yes, just call UIApplication#openURL with the itms-services URL.

Comment: Here is an example on how to call the URL: https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-iOS/blob/develop/Classes/BITUpdateManager.m#L725 The URL to add at the end is the link to the plist file mentioned above.

Comment: @Kerni Does Apple restricted the number of apps (100) if we used this method ?

Comment: This method does NOT change any of the provisioning profile requirements and signing the apps. So with AdHoc profiles you are still restricted to 100 devices, only enterprise profiles do not have this restriction but may only be used for devices that belong to your company according to the license agreement.

Comment: @ashtom when i call UIApplication#openURL with the itms-services URL, my app just quit to the springboard, how do i prevent that ?

Comment: This is the expected behavior, but an alert should appear first to ask you if you want to install the app. Are you sure that your plist is correctly formatted?

Comment: @ashtom Everything work fine,the app is install when user tap on install button, but how do i tracked whenever user click on "install" or "Cancel", i need to do some actions based on user tap ?

Comment: It's not possible to track the button taps. What could work is to check for the applicationDidResignActive / applicationDidBecomeActive events as iOS jumps to the home screen if the user taps "Install".